# Why do package managers like apt and pacman NOT use system proxy settings by default?

Tags: package-management, proxy, pacman, aptitude, defaults

To be clear, this is a question on why the developers of apt chose to set it up this way.  I’m not asking how to change my proxy settings, but rather why the out-of-the-box defaults make me have to configure this when it could be easily auto-configured.

`apt` even has an autodetect proxy settings, I just don’t get why it isn't turned on by default.

Every time I switch to a network with a proxy (like my universities network has one, but my home network doesn’t, so I have to turn the proxy on and off depending on where i’m connecting from) on a new distro I’ve set up, I have to jump into my `apt`/`pacman`/whatever conf and set the proxy up.

Other programs like `wget` and `firefox` just work nicely by using my system proxy by default, yet apt requires the user to go set it up. WHY???

Comment: When you install [Debian](http://debian.org/), a web proxy can be configured

Comment: The common way to handle this is with environment variables.  Apt does support the common HTTP_PROXY variable. Which mechanism would you like apt to support? Mentioned in the manual. https://linux.die.net/man/5/apt.conf

Comment: @PhilipCouling I'd like it to just read the env vars already running

Comment: But that's exactly what they already do. I think perhaps you would like your terminal's environment variables to change when your wife network changes.  That is more tricky because environment variables are copied from the parent process when the process (terminal) starts. The process can rewrite its own variables but there's no mechanism for it to automatically pick up others when the network changes. This isn't the fault of apt, it's the unix process model.

Answer (score 1):

Most command-line programs (like `apt`, `wget`, `curl`, and many others) don't use graphical desktop settings because a) they might not be running under a GUI environment, and b) every DE does things differently, there's no real consistency or standard (and certainly not just one that everybody follows).

Instead, they rely on either their own config files and/or environment variables like `http_proxy`, `https_proxy`, `no_proxy`, etc.

So far, so good.  The trouble is that it's impossible to change a program's environment settings from another program.  So there's no way for those variables to be automatically updated when the network settings change - at least for currently running programs (like bash or whatever else is running).

FYI, see [How to automatically update the $http_proxy variable system wide on network connection?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/648990/how-to-automatically-update-the-http-proxy-variable-system-wide-on-network-conn) for a closely related question (and answer).

Comment: either way it would seem to me to be "sensible defaults" if  it had autodetect proxy as the default behaviour rather than no proxy.